# what is the difference

Tags: sql, database, postgresql, plpgsql

I'm not even sure what this is called?

But I'm trying to learn what the difference is between writing a function like this is in plpgsql:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION foo() RETURNS TRIGGER AS $$
    ....
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

vs

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION foo() RETURNS TRIGGER AS $foo$
    ....
$foo$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

is there a difference when using $$ vs $foo$?   why would someone choose one over another?
perhaps I've just missed some documentation explaining the difference.  If someone could enlighten me, I'd really appreciate it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Whatever you type between the `$` signs after the `AS` becomes the delimiter tag. You could write:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION foo() RETURNS TRIGGER AS $!!unicorns!!$
    ....
$!!unicorns!!$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

The `$...$` notation denotes a [dollar-quoted string constant](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-syntax-lexical.html#SQL-SYNTAX-DOLLAR-QUOTING) in PostgreSQL.

Comment: Allowing different strings enables simpler nesting.